# Neo4j: Get the value for a deleted property

Tags: neo4j

I am using transaction event handlers to do security checking on deleted nodes, to make sure whether a current user is allowed to do this.

To make sure I have the right node to check I first have to find out whether it has a certain property and then check the value of another property, so ideally the code should be something like this:

```
        graphDatabaseService.registerTransactionEventHandler(new TransactionEventHandler.Adapter<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object beforeCommit(TransactionData data) throws Exception {
            for (Node node : data.deletedNodes()) {
                if (node.hasProperty("checkProperty")){
                    if (node.hasProperty("propertyToCheck")){
                        String value = (String) node.getProperty("propertyToCheck");
                        ... do checking on value
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But this fails with exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node[11] has been deleted in this tx
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.WritableTransactionState$CowEntityElement.assertNotDeleted(WritableTransactionState.java:141)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.WritableTransactionState$CowEntityElement.getPropertyAddMap(WritableTransactionState.java:129)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.WritableTransactionState$CowNodeElement.getPropertyAddMap(WritableTransactionState.java:155)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.WritableTransactionState.getCowPropertyAddMap(WritableTransactionState.java:529)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.hasProperty(Primitive.java:306)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.hasProperty(NodeImpl.java:53)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasProperty(NodeProxy.java:160)
```

The only workaround I found is this:

```
            for (Node node : data.deletedNodes()) {
                boolean check = false;
                String valueToCheck = null;
                for (PropertyEntry prop : data.removedNodeProperties()) {
                    if (node.equals(prop.entity())) {
                        if (prop.key().equals("checkProperty")) {
                            check = true;
                        }
                        if (prop.key().equals("propertyToCheck")) {
                            valueToCheck = (String) prop.previouslyCommitedValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (check){
                    ... do checking on value
                }

            }
```

But this goes through ALL deleted properties, so this is obviously not a nice solution.

So my question is: is there a better way to do this?

Using neo4j 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code in `TransactionEventHandler#beforeCommit` is itself part of the transaction you cannot access any property on a deleted node or relationship. As you've discovered the only way to access deleted properties is via `TransactionData#removedNodeProperties()` and `TransactionData#removedRelationshipProperties()`.

You can optimize your code by running a single iteration over `removedNodeProperties()` (just pseudo code below):

```
for (PropertyEntry<Node> pe: data.removedNodeProperties()) {
    if (pe.key().equals("checkProperty")) {
        runCheckForDeletedNodeAndValue(pe.entity(), pe.previouslyCommitedValue())
    }
}

public void runCheckForDeletedNodeAndValue(Node node, Object oldValue) {
   // throw exception if current user is not allowed to delete
   // this will rollback whole transaction
}
```

Your snippet would iterate this collection for each deleted node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are overlooking the fact that based on the existence of 1 property, I need to check the value of another property to base the security decision on. So I still need to have another extra loop. But of course kicking out the deletedNodes loop is a good idea.